# How to compile C++ code with VSCode using Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-code

So far the only articles and answers I have found for compiling C++ code in VSCode have used the GNU toolset. While I'm fine with this, I would like the ability to test my code with Visual C++ as well. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not a full-blown IDE. It's just a simple editor, it doesn't come with its own compiler like Visual Studio does.

Comment: You can try to download [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) and try to configure them. Note there is a link to the VS2017 too. The official doc do not mention it (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) but says that it supports MSBuild. But you can also give the Visual Studio Community a try https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cplusplus/

Comment: I second the recommendation for Visual Studio Community. Everything will work right out of the box.